# Making a binary tree with a constructor with an array parameter

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, binary-tree

I'm currently trying to make my own binary tree by using a constructor with an array of objects as a parameter. I want it to go depth-by-depth, and going left-to-right in each level. I currently have something like this:

```
public BinaryTree(Object... args) {
        makeBinaryTree(args, root, 0);
    }
    public Node makeBinaryTree(Object[] args, Node node, int h) {
        if (h < args.length && root == null) {
            setRoot(new Node(args[0]));
            node.setLeft(makeBinaryTree(args, node.getLeft(), 2 * h + 1));
            node.setRight(makeBinaryTree(args, node.getRight(), 2 * h + 2));
        }
        return root;
    }
```

So if I were to call this: `new BinaryTree(1,2,3,4,5,6)`
it'll look like this:

```
              1
             / \
            2   3
           / \ /
          4  5 6
```

If it's not complete: `new Binary Tree(1,2,3,4,5,7)`
will look like this:

```
          1
         / \
        2   3
       / \   \
      4  5    7
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @zysaaa thought it was pretty self explanatory but to break it down for you, my question Is, is there a way to make the tree using a constructor of an array of objects as a parameter, if so how?

Comment: Yes you can, you need to pass index every time and also keep track of it

Comment: Doesn't your constructor in the code you've provided already takes in an array of objects?

Comment: @HenryTwist  The code he provided didn't work.

Comment: Are you always going to create a *complete* binary tree? What if it is not complete? How should it work?

Comment: @trincot it should still go depth-by-depth and keep going left-to-right, I'll add an example of how it'll look if it's not complete

Comment: What would be the tree produced for, say `new BinaryTree(1,3,4,5,6,7)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- When you make the first call to `makeBinaryTree`,  the `node` argument is `null`, and thus any access to `node.getLeft()`, `node.setLeft()`, ...etc, is invalid. Although `root` receives a value, that is a different variable than the local variable `node`, which does not change by that update ("call by value").
- The second function only creates a new node when `root` is `null`, which happens only once. So in total it will never create more than one single node.
- The second function always returns the `root` node, which is not what you want to get returned from the deeper recursive calls.

It is a better coding pattern when you omit this `Node` parameter completely. Instead let the job of `makeBinaryTree` be to *create* the node for the given index, and *return* it, and let it be ignorant of `root`. That way the first call can assign that returned Node instance to `root`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public BinaryTree(Object... args) {
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        setRoot(makeBinaryTree(args, 0));
    }
}

public Node makeBinaryTree(Object[] args, int h) {
    if (h >= args.length) return null;
    Node node = new Node(args[h]);
    node.setLeft(makeBinaryTree(args, 2 * h + 1));
    node.setRight(makeBinaryTree(args, 2 * h + 2));
    return node;
}
```

If you have a `Node` constructor that can take three arguments (value, left and right), then the second function can be shortened to:

```
public Node makeBinaryTree(Object[] args, int h) {
    return h >= args.length ? null
         : new Node(args[h], 
                    makeBinaryTree(args, 2 * h + 1),
                    makeBinaryTree(args, 2 * h + 2));
}
```