# How to create a tree like structure with a List<CustomType> parameter in java constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor, binary-tree

I have a class **Org** that has **name** and a list of **tasks** and I want to print a list of tasks under each name in a tree like structure using the class constructor:
name -> A tasks - > B, C, name ->B tasks - > D, E, name -> C, tasks -> F,G

```
        A
       / \
     B     C
    / \   / \
   D   E  F  G
```

Here is the class structure:

```
static class Org {
        char name;
        List<Org> tasks;

        Org(char name, List<Org> tasks){
            this.name = name;
            this.tasks = tasks;
        }
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443740/making-a-binary-tree-with-a-constructor-with-an-array-parameter) but it does not apply to what I'm doing.
Here is what I tried

```
 List<Org> org = new Org('A', new ArrayList<Org>('B','C')); // for the first level
 org.add('B', new ArrayList<Org>('D','E')); // for the second level
 org.add('C', new ArrayList<Org>('F','G')); // for the third level
```

This does not work because the second parameter in the constructor expects an Org type and not a char type. How would you create such a tree using this constructor? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a List with only one member. (and empty lists for the leaf nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these problems, we should tackle it bottom up.

```
Org orgG = new Org('G', Arrays.asList());
Org orgF = new Org('F', Arrays.asList());
Org orgE = new Org('E', Arrays.asList());
Org orgD = new Org('D', Arrays.asList());
        
Org orgC = new Org('C', Arrays.asList(orgF, orgG));
Org orgB = new Org('B', Arrays.asList(orgD, orgE));
Org orgA = new Org('A', Arrays.asList(orgC, orgB));
```

With this, if `Org` has empty list means it is a leaf node (no child for it).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Horace Lee but the constructor ```new ArrayList(orgF, orgG) ``` can not take <List, List>, it takes <char, List>, that makes the last 3 lines you suggested not work.

Comment: I guess you meant ```Org orgA = new Org('A', Arrays.asList(orgC, orgB));``` not 
```Org orgA = new Org('A', new ArrayList<Org>(orgC, orgB));```

Comment: @kingified, correct I was referring to `Arrays.asList`, thanks for catching it.
Updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from the bottom up, constructing the child object and passing it to the parent constructor. For the sake of brevity, I'll substitute `Org...` for `List<Org>`:

```
new Org('A',
    new Org('B',
        new Org('D'), new Org('E')),
    new Org('C',
        new Org('F'), new Org('G')))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who faces a similar issue, I was able to get what I needed with this based on the comments and answers provided by contributors.

```
            Org orgG = new Org('G', new ArrayList());
            Org orgF = new Org('F', new ArrayList());
            Org orgE = new Org('E', new ArrayList());
            Org orgD = new Org('D', Arrays.asList(orgH,orgI));
            Org orgC = new Org('C', Arrays.asList(orgF,orgG));
            Org orgB = new Org('B', Arrays.asList(orgD,orgE));
            Org orgA = new Org('A', Arrays.asList(orgB,orgC));
```